# Logging all exceptions occurring in .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a lot of code written from an older winforms project that I was working on. I have recently created a method to log errors (to a database) that occur in a couple try/catch blocks.  Is there a way that I can add this functionality to the application overall whenever the application moves to catch ex as exception, or if an exception somehow goes unhandled, instead of adding it to all my try/catch blocks?

My method is created by the dataset designer to insert a row into the "Error Table" within my DB and looks like:

```
tbladapter.LogError("TRY/CATCH", ex.Message & ";;;; " & ex.InnerException.ToString, My.Application.UserID, Now)
Msgbox("Tell genius he needs to learn how to expect and handle errors!")
```

Comment: What type of project is this? Forms application? Web application?

Comment: @SLC this is a winforms app

Comment: The way you're describing the problem sounds a bit like a use case for something like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) - but that doesn't necessarily mean that this is a good technical solution in your case. I don't know enough about the product to endorse, recommend or explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can catch all exceptions, even when they are being caught by a try/catch block.  You can do so by handling the `FirstChanceException` event of the current `AppDomain`.  To do that, when your application starts, call `AddHandler`, like this:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException, AddressOf FirstChanceExceptionHandler
```

Here's an example handler method:

```
Private Sub FirstChanceExceptionHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString())
End Sub
```

Also, I should mention that using `MsgBox` is generally frowned upon as being a throw-back to VB6.  `MessageBox.Show` is a better option.  Also, you may not be aware that simply calling `ToString` on most exceptions will show the message, source, stack trace, and those of all of the inner exceptions as well.  Calling `ToString` is easier than accessing all those separate properties too.

Answer (score 0):

In a windows forms application, there is `ThreadException` event on the `Application` that you can hook into. This method runs whenever an exception occurs within your application.

In the class (maybe Program.vb?) that creates the form, you can add something like

`Application.ThreadException += New ThreadExceptionEventHandler(form1.someHandler)`

to handle it within your form.

Comment: The `Application.ThreadException` is only raised for untrapped exceptions.

Comment: @SLC Are you referring to this event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx 

"This event allows your Windows Forms application to handle otherwise unhandled exceptions that occur in Windows Forms threads."  This will not trap any exceptions handled in my try/catch is that correct?

Comment: You can trap an exception and re-throw it though, just by putting `throw;` in your catch block. This is what I do when logging exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar in a web project a while ago and used the Exception Handling Block features in the Enterprise Library

There is a good starting point [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649086.aspx) and I'm sure you can find others.

From memory I think It was fairly easy to implement as I was auto creating support tickets from the output.